# How to have external app as requirement for installation of app widget?

Tags: android, installation, widget, manifest

I hava an app. External to the app, as a second .apk I have an app widget, which accesses the app's db via a ContentProvider.
So the app widget only works, if the app is installed.

I would like to have the following scenario:

1. When a user attempts to install the app widget, the installation should abort and inform the user, that he has to install the app, too.
2. When a user uninstalls the app, the app widget should be removed, too, or alternatively
3. the user should be informed, that Unistallation of the app will break the widget.

Is there a way to accomplish this, ie. with some setting in the app widgets manifest?
If not, what other options/scenarios are available?
Minimum SDK is 7, target SDK is 8.

Note: Having both the widget and the app in the same apk is not an option as the app is  large and installs to the SD card, while app widgets must be installed on the internal memory. That is the reason for the separation.

Comment: why don't you check after widget installation, if the content provider is available? if not installed, just show a fallback message, like "please install app xyz".

Comment: because the the earliest point in time to do that, would be a configuration activity. While possible, this is not an elegant nor user-friendly scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a user attempts to install the app widget, the installation should abort and inform the user, that he has to install the app, too.

If by "install the app widget" you mean "install the APK containing the app widget", this is not possible.

If by "install the app widget" you mean "add the app widget to the home screen", you might be able to rig up something using a configuration activity. This will more or less boil down to alex's answer in the comment.

> When a user uninstalls the app, the app widget should be removed, too, or alternatively

This is not possible.

> the user should be informed, that Unistallation of the app will break the widget.

That too is not possible. However, once the user uninstall the one APK, the app widget APK could have a `BroadcastReceiver` watching for `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`, and then let the user know about the problem.

> If not, what other options/scenarios are available? Minimum SDK is 7, target SDK is 8.

Don't bother with the app widget until Android 3.0+ becomes sufficient dominant that you are willing to package it in the main APK, as "install to external storage" has no real meaning on Android 3.0+.

Comment: with "install the app widget" I meant "instakk the APK containing the app widget". Sad state of affairs - waiting for Anddroid 3.0+ becoming more dominant means waiting for 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich becoming more dominant on phones :(